# Como puedo hacer con CSS que mi <header> en display:flex con 3 <div> hijos no se modifique al cambiar de tamaño la ventana del navegador

Tags: css, html5

He probado con medidas en px, en porcentajes, finalmente estoy estudiándolo con Flex y parecía que funcionaba pero cuando cambio de tamaño la ventana del navegador, el  central que se corresponde con el texto **desarrollo de app web** cambia de tamaño y no quiero.
Si utilizo las propiedades height y width en porcentaje no me deja poner el tamaño que quiero o se desborda porque me exige mayor a 100% y si pongo en px, al cambiar el tamaño de la ventana también se desborda.

De la siguente forma se ajusta pero no con los tamaños que yo quiero

```css
.cabecera{
    width: 91rem;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
     box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      
}
#cabeza{
    width: 40%;
    align-content: stretch;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color: gray
    
}
#cabezatxt{
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
    text-decoration: overline;
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    flex-grow:0;

    
}
#imagenbn{
    width: 30%;
    align-content: stretch;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        
}
#foto{
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 20px;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   flex-grow: 10;
}
#logo{
    width: 10%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    align-content: stretch;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#img1{
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 20px;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   flex-grow: 10;
   
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { #cabeza h1{ font-size: 1rem; } }

nav{
    height: 7rem;
    width: 91rem;
   
    
}
.botones{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    flex-shrink: 10;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    
}
.botones button{
    height: 3rem;
    width: 7rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 1rem;
    text-decoration-style: solid;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray;

}
button:hover{background-color: gainsboro}
button:active {
  text-shadow:2px 2px #000000; 
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .botones{ font-size: 1rem; } }

    
#parati{
   box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 2rem;;
    z-index:1;
    width: 150px;
    height: 9rem; 
}
.columna{
    float: left;
    height: 30rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow:  15px 15px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    
}
p{
   font-family: monospace;
   text-align: center;
   font-size:1rem;
   justify-content: center;
    
        
}
.bloque{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
section{
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 30rem;
    width: 60%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    box-shadow:  15px 15px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
    
    
}
.seccion{
    text-align: center;
    background-color:gainsboro;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
        
}

}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { .seccion{ font-size: 1rem; } }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
      <title>Desarrollo de app WEB</title>
      <meta name="author" content=" "/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="miestilo.css"/>
    </head>

<body>
    <header>
     <div class="cabecera">
        <div id="logo">
         <img id="img1" src="imagenes/daw.png"/>
        </div>
        <div id="cabeza">
              <h1 id="cabezatxt">Desarrollo de app WEB</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="imagenbn">    
         <img id="foto" src="imagenes/imagenbn.jpeg"/>
        </div>
     </div>
    </header><br><br>
    
  <nav>
      <div class="botones">
        <div class="boton">
            <button input type="button">Sobre mi</button>
        </div>
        <div class="boton">
            <button input type="button">Contacto</button>
        </div>
        <div class="boton">
            <button input type="button">Libros</button>
        </div>
         <div class="boton">
            <button input type="button">Ejercicios</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
      
  </nav><br><br><br>
    
 <div class="bloque">   
  <aside class="columna">
         <figure>
           <img id="parati" src="imagenes/parati.png"/>
         </figure>  
         <header>
           <h4>ESTO ES PARA TI</h4>
         </header> 
         <p>Por que sé lo complicado <br>que puede ser comenzar<br>el camino            <br>del <strong>desarrollo WEB</strong><br> y las horas que      
         puedes<br>llegar a invertir<br> en buscar por la red</p>  
      
  </aside> 
          
  
  <section>
    <div class="seccion">
      <div id="que">
        <h1>QUE VAS A ENCONTRAR</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="sobremi">  
        <article>
          <h3>Sobre mi</h3>
            <ul>
             <li>Grado Universitario Enfermería</li>
             <li>Grado Superior DAW</li>  
             <li>Curriculum</li>
          </ul>
       </article>
     </div>
     <div id="contenidos">
       <article >
          <h3>Contenidos</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Ejercicios de programación</li>
              <li>Bibliografía</li>
              <li>Enlaces de interés</li>
              <li>Videos Tutoriales</li>  
            </ul>
      </article>
     </div>
    </div>
    
  </section>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Puedes insertar un _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en tu pregunta. Por cierto, ten en cuenta que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_ (no todos pueden ver las imágenes, y no se puede hacer _copypaste_ de una imagen) :)

Comment: @padaleiana muchas gracias por tus consejos. Espero hacerme pronto con el uso de la plataforma y mejorar mis cuestiones. Creo que mi pregunta ahora está mejor expuesta y será mas fácil ayudarme. Un saludo

Comment: Y por qué no usas ```@mediascreen``` para ir adaptando dichas cajas al tamaño de pantalla. Te aconsejo que trabajes con **rem** para un correcto responsive design y no **px**

Comment: @DBE muchas gracias, aun no había visto ese recurso. Me pongo con ello a ver que tal. Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada amigo, es facil, simplemente al final de tu **CSS** debes añadir dichas reglas y vas adapantando el diseño a tu gusto, prueba añadir esta linea al final de tu CSS y veras como se cambia la fuente *h1* cuando el ancho es inferior a *900px*: ```@media screen and (max-width: 900px) { #cabeza h1{ font-size: 1rem; } }```

Comment: @DBE gracias. Es genial, funciona. Ahora tengo otro problema parecido. Mi <section> se mueve hacia abajo y no quiero. Quiero que todo el bloque y su contenido disminuyan de tamaño para que siga en la misma posición, justo al lado de un <aside>La verdad es que aún no controlo mucho de dimensiones y porcentajes, he usado rem como me decias también pero no hay manera. Todo el bloque sección se me desplaza hacia abajo y no consigo mantenerlo al lado del <aside>. Lo de dentro del bloque <section> son 3 <div> en Flex Column

Comment: A que parte te refieres con ```<section``` y ```<aside>``` ya que no lo veo en tu ejemplo, si quieres edita tu pregunta y añades dicha parte con sus estilos, y a ver si te puedo ayudar. Por ejemplo, el ancho de tus cajas puedes trabajarlo en **%** si deseas, pero si quieres que se adopten tus *fuentes*, *márgenes*, *padding*, etc. debes trabajarlo con **rem**.

Comment: @DBE he editado de nuevo con mas detalle. Creo que estoy cerca pero no termino de acertar. Como puedes ver al ejecutar, la caja de la sección se me va aplastando hasta que no cabe y se desplaza. No se como hacer para que ajuste el tamaño de todo el bloque y no se desplace. Como los elementos del header por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores que son normal cuando uno está aprendiendo, te aconsejo que leas bien el [manual HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) y [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) de cómo usar las etiquetas HTML.

Para que tu bloque se adopte automático puedes usar por ejemplo:

```
.bloque {
   width: 100%; /* ancho 100% */
   max-width: 90%; /* maximo permitido del 90% */
}
```

Ahora, si buscas información en internet aconsejan usar **rem**, **em** y no **pixeles**, es importante saber que, según las especificaciones, la unidad PX de CSS no equivale a un píxel de visualización física.

Si ponemos en nuestro body (cuerpo):

```
body {
 font-size: 18px; 
}

p { 
    font-size: 1rem; /* 1rem equivale a 18px */
    padding: 0.5rem; /* 0.5 rem seria 9px */
 }
```

1. Te deja una guía de aprendizaje muy bueno sobre [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
2. También es interesante saber la guía [Media queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) para dispositivos estándares.

**Posible ejemplo:**

```css
/*
* HTML reglas basicas
*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

article,
div,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
nav,
section,
pre,
video {
  display: block;
}


/* importante para diseño responsivo */

audio,
iframe,
img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  /*  1 rem equivale ahora a 18px */
}

body {
  font-family: workSans, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* !Important */
  position: relative;
  /* Important */
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Encabezados */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: .8rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: .7rem;
}


/* parrafos */

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .7em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
}


/* Encabezado */

.cabecera {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#cabeza {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40%;
  align-content: stretch;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: gray
}

#cabezatxt {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  text-decoration: overline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#imagenbn {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30%;
  align-content: stretch;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#foto {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#logo {
  width: 10%;
  align-content: stretch;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#img1 {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  flex-grow: 10;
}


/* Menu principal  */

nav {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.botones {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.botones .boton {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.botones li.boton a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}

.botones li.boton a:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.botones li.boton a:active {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
}


/* Estructura de tu ASIDE con SECTION */

.bloque {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bloque .aside {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

#parati {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.bloque .section {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}


/**
 *  @MEDIA SCREEN, esto va al final de tu documento siempre, te aconsejo no repetir dos veces los mismo y que vaya en orden segun los pixeles.
 *  
 */

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  #cabeza {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
  #imagenbn {
    max-width: 20%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #cabeza h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  /* Cambiamos menu principal  */
  .botones {
    padding: .5rem;
    gap: .5rem;
  }
  .botones li.boton a {
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .bloque {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .bloque .aside,
  .bloque .section {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    order: 2;
  }
  /* puedes ordenador tus cajes por si quieres que primero aparesco el section y no tu aside, aunque este en tu html este mas abajo :) */
  .bloque .section {
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    /*  1 rem equivale ahora a 16px */
  }
  #cabeza h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  #cabeza h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  /* Cambiamos menu principal  */
  .botones {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .botones li.boton {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: .5rem 0;
  }
  .botones li.boton a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="cabecera">
      <div id="logo">
        <img id="img1" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-company-logo_53876-120501.jpg?t=st=1647351946~exp=1647352546~hmac=987626ed5376ad7b5c5e8adbd0832b38782e1879ad54bad26d2236199abfc972&w=740" />
      </div>

      <div id="cabeza">
        <h1 id="cabezatxt">Desarrollo de app WEB</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="imagenbn">
        <img id="foto" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <br>
  <br>

  <nav>
    <ul class="botones">
      <li class="boton">
        <a href="sobre-mi.html">Sobre mi</a>
      </li>

      <li class="boton">
        <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
      </li>

      <li class="boton">
        <a href="libros.html">Libros</a>
      </li>

      <li class="boton">
        <a href="ejercicios.html">Ejercicios</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="bloque">
    <aside class="aside">
      <figure>
        <img id="parati" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/rain-water-green-leaf-macro_1150-12802.jpg?t=st=1647354754~exp=1647355354~hmac=bb9a2270e736c024505070ce1ce0b315ca6776a99c9074728ee21e1b60b33ca4&w=996" />
      </figure>

      <h2>ESTO ES PARA TI</h2>

      <p>Por que sé lo complicado<br> que puede ser comenzar<br> el camino<br> del <strong>desarrollo WEB</strong><br> y las horas que puedes<br> llegar a invertir<br> en buscar por la red</p>
    </aside>

    <section class="section">

      <div id="que">
        <h1>QUE VAS A ENCONTRAR</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="sobremi">
        <article>
          <h3>Sobre mi</h3>
          <ul class="block">
            <li>Grado Universitario Enfermería</li>
            <li>Grado Superior DAW</li>
            <li>Curriculum</li>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </div>

      <div id="contenidos">
        <article>
          <h3>Contenidos</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>Ejercicios de programación</li>
            <li>Bibliografía</li>
            <li>Enlaces de interés</li>
            <li>Videos Tutoriales</li>
          </ul>
        </article>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Ahora veamos un ejemplo usando **Grid**, si te quieres modernizar usaría esta estructura.

Aquí una guía de cómo usar [GRID](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

**Ejemplo grid:**

```css
/* Colores estandares, asi podras hacer facilmente cambios */
:root {
  --color-body: #2D2F39;
  --color-primary: #5A5f72;
  --color-secundary: #e15d44;
  --color-link: blue;
  --color-link-hover: darkblue;
}


/*
* HTML reglas basicas
*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

article,
div,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
nav,
section,
pre,
video {
  display: block;
}


/* importante para diseño responsivo */

audio,
iframe,
img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  /*  1 rem equivale ahora a 18px */
}

body {
  color: var(--color-body);
  font-family: workSans, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* !Important */
  position: relative;
  transition: color linear;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* Encabezados */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: .8rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: .7rem;
}


/* parrafos */

p {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: .7em;
}

a {
  color: var(--color-link);
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color linear;
}

a:hover {
  color: var(--color-link-hover);
  transition: color linear;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block {
  list-style-type: square;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 1rem;
}


/* Grid base layout  */

.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Grid layout */
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-template-areas: 
  "header header header header" 
  "navegador navegador navegador navegador" 
  "aside contenido contenido contenido" 
  "footer footer footer footer";
}


/* Area: HEADER */

.contenedor .header {
  background-color: #7575a3;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: header;
}

.contenedor .header #header__logo img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  height: 9rem;
  width: 9rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.contenedor .header #header_title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.contenedor .header #header__img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 16.6rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* Area: NAVEGADOR  */


/* Menu principal  */

nav#navegador {
  grid-area: navegador;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.botones {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.botones .boton {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.botones li.boton a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all linear;
}

.botones li.boton a:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  transition: all linear;
}

.botones li.boton a:active {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
}


/* Area: CONTENT */

.contenedor .contenido {
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 50vh;
  grid-area: contenido;
}


/* Area: ASIDE */

.contenedor .aside {
  background-color: var(--color-primary);
  grid-area: aside;
  padding: 1rem;
}


/* Area: FOOTER */

.contenedor .footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: var(--color-body);
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 40vh;
  padding: 0 2rem 0 1rem;
  /* Flex, puedes usarlo en tu grid-area */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
  html,
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    /*  1 rem equivale ahora a 16px */
  }
  /* Nueva reglas encabezado */
  .contenedor .header #header__logo img {
    height: 6rem;
    width: 6rem;
    min-width: 6rem;
  }
  .contenedor .header #header_title {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
  .contenedor .header #header__img img {
    max-width: 9rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  /* Grid base layout - cambiamos estructura segun pantalla  */
  .contenedor {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "navegador navegador navegador navegador" "contenido contenido contenido contenido" "aside aside aside aside" "footer footer footer footer";
  }
  /* Cambiamos menu principal  */
  .botones {
    padding: .5rem;
    gap: .5rem;
  }
  .botones li.boton a {
    font-size: .8rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .contenedor .header {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .contenedor .header #header__img img {
    max-width: 100rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos1.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="contenedor">

    <header class="header">
      <div id="header__logo">
        <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-company-logo_53876-120501.jpg?t=st=1647351946~exp=1647352546~hmac=987626ed5376ad7b5c5e8adbd0832b38782e1879ad54bad26d2236199abfc972&w=740" alt="" height="100" width="100" />
      </div>

      <div id="header_title">
        <h1>Desarrollo de app WEB</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="header__img">
        <img id="foto" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/wide-angle-shot-single-tree-growing-clouded-sky-during-sunset-surrounded-by-grass_181624-22807.jpg?t=st=1647352028~exp=1647352628~hmac=87aeedb0e58a980b194295ed79873aee37f170de8395c8148975241ec3559ba1&w=996"
        />
      </div>
    </header>

    <nav id="navegador">
      <ul class="botones">
        <li class="boton">
          <a href="sobre-mi.html">Sobre mi</a>
        </li>

        <li class="boton">
          <a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>
        </li>

        <li class="boton">
          <a href="libros.html">Libros</a>
        </li>

        <li class="boton">
          <a href="ejercicios.html">Ejercicios</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="contenido">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br> consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br> cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br> proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <br>

      <h2>Titulo h2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br> consequat.
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br> cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br> proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

      <a href="index.hmtl">Home</a>
    </section>

    <aside class="aside">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod<br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br> quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br> consequat.
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br> cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br> proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </aside>


    <footer class="footer">
      <div>
        LOGO
      </div>

      <div>
        Links
      </div>

      <div>
        Direccion
      </div>
    </footer>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mil gracias. Iré profundizando más en ello según avance en mis estudios, apenas llevo 2 semanas con esta asignatura. Entiendo entonces que los contenedores deben tener tamaño en % y todo lo que contienen en medidas relativas como rem. Un saludo, ha sido de gran ayuda

Comment: @JoseL. Me alegro amigo, para dos semanas vas muy bien, no es que sea obligado, ya que por ejemplo ```.block { width: 100%; max-width: 1300px; margin: 0 auto;``` también te va funcionar, sería una caja centrada con máximo de ancho de *1300px*, pero si la pantalla es inferior a *1300px* este se va adaptar al *100%*, es depende un poco del diseño, aunque ya sabiendo que *1rem* equivale por defecto a *16px*, puedes calcular fácil y la que personalmente uso. Puedes aceptar la respuesta si piensas que te ayudo, y así se queda cerrada. Suerte con tu proyecto. Un Saludo