# Problema con el margen en css

Tags: html, css

Estoy comenzando con **CSS**, leyendo un manual.

Mi problema es el siguiente, establezco un *margen* global de **0px**, luego tengo un `div` con 4 párrafos dentro, y solo a uno por medio de su clase le asigno un *margen* de **10px**, luego fuera del `div` coloco otro párrafo con la misma clase que este último, al mostrar la página en **Firefox** se ve que el `div` tiene un espaciado previo y no entiendo como surgió ni cómo sacarlo.

Intente establecer un espaciado de *margen* **0** para ese `div` en el archivo **CSS** y no cambio la situación. Acompaño los códigos:

**pseudoclases.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Este texto es el título del documento</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pseudoclases.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<p class="mitexto1">Mi texto1</p>
<p class="mitexto2">Mi texto2</p>
<p class="mitexto3">Mi texto3</p>
<p class="mitexto4">Mi texto4</p>
</div>
<p class="mitexto2">Mi texto2 fuera del div</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**pseudoclases.css**

```
p:nth-child(2){
    background: greenyellow;
}
*{
    margin: 0px;
}

p:nth-child(odd){
    background: orange;
}
p:nth-child(even){
    background: blue;
}
:not(.mitexto2){
    margin: 10px;
}
div > p.mitexto2{
    background: green;
}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayudar y gracias por la atención.

Comment: Con esta línea ```:not(.mitexto2)``` estas estableciendo un ```margin: 10px``` a cualquier elemento que **NO** sea ```.mitexto2```, luego esta línea debería ir al principio ```* {   margin: 0px; }``` para establecer el margen por defecto a 0 en todo el documento.

Comment: Perdón, que distracción la mia. Te agradezco mucho la respuesta. Pregunta respondida. Voy a averiguar como cerrar la prefgunta. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Ahora te dejo una respuesta y así lo puedes cerrar. Si estas aprendiendo, aquí tienes muchos ejemplos de donde puedes aprender: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp, saludos

Comment: Gracias @DBE, me fue muy útil tu información. Perdón pero no encuentro en la documentacion como cerrar la pregunta. Apenas lo encuetre la cierro. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Te acabo de dejar una respuesta, arriba de mi respuesta veras un **0** y un triángulo hacia arriba o hacia bajo, si aprietas hacia arriba, votas la pregunta a favor, hacia bajo sería negativo, y si piensa que te ayudo mi respuesta, veras un **V** también, si le das clic, estarías aceptando mi respuesta y cierras tu pregunta, te aconsejo que hagas un recorrido del sitio, y así aprendes como usar el sitio, un saludo amigo.

Comment: puedes añadir una imagen de como queda y dale bordes a todo para ver cada caja sus limites. gracias

Comment: Gracias @DBE no entenida porque no podia puntuar y luego de seguir tu onsejo descubri que tenia que esperar al menos 15miutos desde mi publicación para poder hacer. Gracs por tu ayuda y paciencia.

Comment: Gracias FranyxD, muy buena idea. Lo probaré.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas un poco confuso de cómo usar la pseudoclase `:not()` ya que no selecciona dicho elemento, si no selecciona cualquier elemento que no se llama en este caso **.mitexto2**, y por eso estas añadiendo un *margin* de **10px** a todos tus elementos que no se llaman así.

Si miramos el manual, nos dice:

> Selecciona cualquier elemento que NO sea un párrafo

```
:not(p) {
  color: blue;
}
```

Otra cosa importante tener en cuenta en tu **CSS** `* { margin: 0px; }` deberia ir al principio de tu documento, para que este coja efecto sobre todo tu hojas de estilos.

Personalmente lo reinicio de esta forma:

**estilos.css**

```
/* Reseteo por defecto */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

article,
div,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
nav,
section,
pre,
video {
 display: block;
}
/* ¡importante para diseño responsivo! asi se adopta automatica a dimesion pantalla */
audio,
iframe,
img,
video {
 max-width: 100%;
}

html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* Añades estilos por defecto a todo el cuerpo */
body {
 color: #3C3B37;
 font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 16px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Sigues con tu CSS */

p:nth-child(2){
 background: greenyellow;
}
/* etc ...*/
```

Si estas aprendiendo te dejo un enlace con mucho ejemplo buenos, que te pueden ayudar a orientarte y coger más experiencia: [W3Schools How To](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp)

También tienes interesantes respuestas en SOes: [Guías de estilo oficiales para HTML, CSS y Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22406/gu%C3%ADas-de-estilo-oficiales-para-html-css-y-javascript)

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Toda esta información me esta siendo muy útil. Tengo mucho que aprender y me esto me ayuda muchu. Gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo, me alegro de que te sirvió, que mejor que ayudar. Aquí te dejo otra respuesta que di, que también es interesante para aprender, crear una estructura con **GRID**: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520150/como-puedo-hacer-con-css-que-mi-header-en-displayflex-con-3-div-hijos-no-se/520734#520734. Puedes aceptar esta respuesta si piensa que te soluciono el problema dando clic en la **V** donde se vota, y se pondrá verde, en la parte de arriba de mi pregunta, y así queda cerrada tu pregunta, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu pronta respuesta y por estar siempre predispuesto a ayudar espero poder retribuirtelo en algún momento. Te mando un abrazo. Y decidí pausar el libro q estoy leyendo y segur los manuales que dejaste en ese post. Muy valiosa toda la info que das.

Comment: Me alegro amigo, poco a poco cogerás experiencia. Céntrate primero en **HTML** y **CSS** así aprendes el *Frontend* y después si te quieres profundizar más ya aprendes algún idioma de programación que te guste (*backend*), ya que hay muchos. Yo aprendí así, icé un máster, libros, etc. y realmente donde más aprendí fue gratis con videos tutoriales que hay muchos y los manuales.

Comment: Gracias por todos tus consejos. En estos momentos estos haciendo como comentas leyendo libros y viendo videos.